# How to get the id while uploading a file

Tags: php, forms, pdo

this is my gallery.php;

```
<br>
<center><form action="galleryuploadxd.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Category
        <select>
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option id_image="1" value="1">Admin Images</option>
        <option id_image="2" value="2">User Images</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>

        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form></center>
```

So i want the option tag `id_images` to be written in my database. I did something like this.

galleryuploadxd.php;

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['sess_user_id']) && $_SESSION['sess_user_id'] != "") {
} else {
    header('location:index.php');
}
?>
<body style="background-color: lightgray"></body>
<center><img src="../images/x.png"></center>

<?php
include "db.php";

$id = $_GET['id_image'];
$target_file2 = "random-dir/";
$target_dir = "randomdir/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$target_file3 = $target_file2 .$target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<h1><center>File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . "." ."</center></h1>";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<h1><center>File is not an image.</center></h1>";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<h1><center>Sorry, file already exists.</center></h1>";
    echo "<h1><a href = gallery-edit.php>Go back </a></h1>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<h1><center>Sorry, your file is too large.</center></h1>";
    echo "<h1><a href = gallery-edit.php>Go back </a></h1>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<h1><center>Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.</center></h1>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<h1><center>Sorry, your file was not uploaded.</center></h1>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<h1><center><a href = gallery-edit.php>Go back </a></center></h1>";


} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "<h1><center>The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.</center></h1>";
        echo " <meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"5;url=gallery-edit.php\" />";
        echo "<center><h1>You Will be redicted to user gallery in 5 seconds...</h1></center>";
        echo "<center><h1>If your browser doesn't support redict please<a href=gallery-edit.php> click here </h1></a></center>";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO categories (id,image_link) VALUES (:id,:image_link)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindValue(':image_link', $target_file3);
        $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
    } else {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<center>Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.</center>";
        echo " <center><a href = gallery-edit.php>Go back </a></center>";
    }
}
?>
```

So in the galleryuploadxd.php i say in the beginning `$id = $_GET['id_image'];` and after in the end

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO categories (id,image_link) VALUES (:id,:image_link)";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bindValue(':image_link', $target_file3);
            $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
            $result = $stmt->execute();
```

i get the error that id cannot be null why doesn't it get the id can anyone help me?

the error;

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id' cannot be null in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\xxxx-admin\galleryuploadxd.php:75 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\xxxx-admin\galleryuploadxd.php(75): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\xxxx-admin\galleryuploadxd.php on line 75

It tells me I can't get the `id`. how can I get the id on the option thats all? I need i'm trying to categorize the uploads thats why i'm doing something like this.

Thanks for the helps!

Comment: The message seems very self explanatory to me. I would say that `$id` has no value

Comment: You need a `name="something"` in the `<select>` tag and not in the `<option>` tag

Comment: If you POST data you will find it in the `$_POST` array and not the `$_GET` array

Comment: @RiggsFolly but i need every select tag with different id how can i do that?

Comment: `<select name="user_type">` then $_POST['user_type']` hold the ONE option selected.

Comment: Then remove `id_image="1"` from all the `<option id_image="1" value="1">Admin Images</option>` as that is a nonsense attribute

Comment: Maybe you should do a Basic HTML tutorial. Remember SO is not a tutorial site

Comment: @RiggsFolly what do you mean by hold the one option?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i need to categorize with id's when uploading to datebase so in my gallery lets say i'll just show id 3 in cars category and houses in id 2

Comment: A select dropdown allows you to select one option from many possible options. The Select tag holds the NAME that will be used to pass the data to the `$_POST` array

Comment: @RiggsFolly after doing `<select name="user_type">` in my php what should i type? after `$id = `  let's say they choose admin uploads i need there id or value to be passed on datebase

Comment: Why do have: `<option value="">Select...</option>` as an option that can be used? Don't do this.

Comment: @RyanVincent I have no idea i started off with categorizing my posts with there id's but lets say they want to post it in admin uploads in my datebase i need the id , every category needs and id

Comment: yes i need something else that can have a value so like i said in my table i have id and image_link if i choose admin images i want the id 1 and user images id 2 so some type of categorizing in id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you don't set the name of your select input

```
<select name="id_image">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option value="1">Admin Images</option>
        <option value="2">User Images</option>
 </select>
```

use this as `$id = $_POST['id_image'];`

Comment: No error this time but i choose admin images and upload an image i don't see it in my table i have id and image_link i need the value 1 when i choose admin images to be id in my table that's all

Comment: did u changed the value of $id

Comment: i need the id to upon choosing from the options if they choose admin images the value will be 1 and user images needs to be 2

Comment: change $id = $_GET['id_image']; to $id = $_POST['id_image'];

Comment: is your categories table have only (id,image_link)

Comment: yes i did , i need the value 1 to be uploaded as id in my table admin images has value 1

Comment: Okay i got the error now thanks for your help,idea !

Comment: ok i understand your problem,just add 1 more colum in your table named as image_id and donot delete id.use use image_id as your id

Comment: Can i message you on twitter?

Answer (score -1):

In your form the method is POST and you try to retreive the records with

```
$id = $_GET['id_image'];
```

you should do:

```
$id = $_POST['id_image'];
```

Comment: Would be useful to add what I said in my comment about where the `name=""` attribute belongs to make this a complete answer

Comment: But beware the code vampire, code this bad will normally require a complete rewrite and the OP wont credit you until you have fixed all their errors